# How to format "=>" to become like in the picture?

Tags: css, json, visual-studio-code

Just found this on youtube. So i just wondering how to automatically format "=>" to something like in redlined section

[image]

I've tried to google it but seems hard to find matching keyword for this

Comment: An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)?

Comment: You need a ligature-based font like FiraCode https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode

Comment: So, is your question about formatting the code in [tag:css] or in [tag:visual-studio-code]? Also why have you included the [tag:json] tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search term you are looking for is `font with programming ligatures` :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could be the automatic code replacement of phpStorm
for arrow functions as mentioned here:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000024550-Turn-off-ASCII-arrows-replacement-on-unicode-arrows